# Assign dataframe values of one set of rows to another set of rows based on a condition for specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign df values of rows of some specific columns to other rows based on a condition.
When I do the following it works because the number of weeks below week level 2 or equal is the same for both sides of the assignment.

```
data = {'year': [2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021],
'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'week': [1,2,3,4,1,2,4],
'value':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df


      year id  week value
0   2020    1   1   0.1
1   2020    1   2   0.2
2   2020    1   3   0.3
3   2020    1   4   0.4
4   2021    1   1   0.5
5   2021    1   2   0.6
6   2021    1   4   0.7
```

assignment:

```
df.loc[(df['year'] == 2021) & (df['week']<= 2),'value'] = df.loc[(df['year'] == 2020) & (df['week']<= 2),'value'].to_numpy()
df
```

result:

```
    year    id  week value
0   2020    1   1   0.1
1   2020    1   2   0.2
2   2020    1   3   0.3
3   2020    1   4   0.4
4   2021    1   1   0.1
5   2021    1   2   0.2
6   2021    1   4   0.7
```

however when I change the assignment to be above week 2, it won't work because the size of both sides isn't equal:

```
df.loc[(df['year'] == 2021) & (df['week']>= 2),'value'] = df.loc[(df['year'] == 2020) & (df['week']>= 2),'value'].to_numpy()
df
```

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an
> iterable

I tried to do that without .to_numpy() but then I got NaN for 2021.

EDIT:
When I use without .to_numpy() here is what I get:

```
df.loc[(df['year'] == 2021) & (df['week']<= 2),'value'] = df.loc[(df['year'] == 2020) & (df['week']<= 2),'value']
df

    year   id week value
0   2020    1   1   0.1
1   2020    1   2   0.2
2   2020    1   3   0.3
3   2020    1   4   0.4
4   2021    1   1   NaN
5   2021    1   2   NaN
6   2021    1   4   0.7
```

Weeks 1 and 2 of 2021 shouldn't get NaN in that case.

While the manual solution here is "simple", and I could just not use the problematic weeks at question, it is not scalable and I could not use that in my main df that contains tens of thousands of records.

Note - the missing weeks in this example are for the 2021 weeks, hence for the assignment destination, however it is possible that the missing weeks are in 2020 as well, so the solution would have to answer this situation as well

**What is the most efficient way to overlook these missing weeks when I try to do such an assignment and just assign for existing ones from both sides?**

Comment: if "overlooking" is what you want, why are nans bad? Can you show *expected* output?

Comment: @Gulzar I'm getting NaN not for the missing values but for the entire assignment range when I don't use .to_numpy(). I added an example

Comment: If the length is not equal, then by which criteria you wanna fill those values?  You can fill it with mean df['value']  = df['value'].fillna(value = df.loc[(df['year'] == 2020) & (df['week']>= 2)].value.mean())

Comment: I simplified the problem for handling the criteria.

Comment: @Nk03 I don't want to fill anything for the NAs. I just want to sub the values for the rows that meet the criteria

Comment: @HermanK How do you want to handle the case when `size of both sides isn't equal`? What will the expected output in such case?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma 
Keep value as is without the assignment for that specific row (if the value to assign is missing). If the row of destination is missing, don't add or anything. Just don't do anything

Comment: Consider your first condition `(df['year'] == 2021) & (df['week']>= 2)` this will select the rows with the indces `5, 6` while the condition `(df['year'] == 2020) & (df['week']>= 2)` will select the rows with indices `1, 2, 3` and I'm still not sure how would you got about assigning the values at index `1, 2, 3` to the values at `5, 6` because pandas align data on indices so it doesn't make sense..May be you want something else?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I see. I'll rephrase perhaps. If weeks are matching between the 2 separate years, I want to assign the value of the matching 2020 week to that of the 2021 matching week. Given that writing the conditions as I did and you repeated produces the problem of different lengths, any other type of solution would work and be appreciated.

Comment: @HermanK Can you show the expected output for the given dataframe?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Hey.. It seems like the answer below does what I expect. Thank you for helping me understand a bit more though.

Comment: @HermanK Glad the answer given by corralien worked for you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first try based on index:

1. Set `["year", "id", "week"]` as index of your dataframe:

```
>>> df = df.set_index(["year", "id", "week"])
>>> df
              value
year id week
2020 1  1       0.1
        2       0.2
        3       0.3
        4       0.4
2021 1  1       0.5  # change to 0.1
        2       0.6  # change to 0.2
        4       0.7
```

2. Select subset of your dataframe as new values:

```
>>> vals = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2020, :, range(3)]]
>>> vals
              value
year id week
2020 1  1       0.1
        2       0.2
```

3. Modify index of new values (2020 → 2021)

```
>>> vals.index = vals.index.set_levels([2021], level="year")
>>> vals
              value
year id week
2021 1  1       0.1
        2       0.2
```

4. Update your dataframe with new values

```
>>> df.update(vals)
>>> df
              value
year id week
2020 1  1       0.1
        2       0.2
        3       0.3
        4       0.4
2021 1  1       0.1  # changed from 0.5
        2       0.2  # changed from 0.6
        4       0.7
```

For `week >= 2`:

```
>>> df = df.set_index(["year", "id", "week"])
>>> vals = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2020, :, range(2, 10)]]
>>> vals.index = vals.index.set_levels([2021], level="year")
>>> df.update(vals)
>>> df
              value
year id week
2020 1  1       0.1
        2       0.2
        3       0.3
        4       0.4
2021 1  1       0.5
        2       0.2  # changed from 0.6
        4       0.4  # changed from 0.7
```

**Update**: use `df.query` instead of `df.loc`

Replace:

```
>>> df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2020, :, range(3)]]
>>> df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2020, :, range(2, 10)]]
```

By:

```
>>> df.query("(year == 2020) and (week <= 2)")
>>> df.query("(year == 2020) and (week >= 2)")
```

It's much more intuitive!